# In AngularJS 1.6, how to avoid a error [ngModel:numfmt] even if ng-if is correct?

Tags: angularjs, types, numbers

I have a weird bug. I need to display an input[type="text"] or input[type="number"] depending of a value in a condition ng-if :

```
 {{ column.item === 'number' }}
 <input ng-model="inserts[pointers.headings.content.tabInserts - 1].dados[0][columnId].value"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="{{ column.default }}"
        ng-if="column.item === 'text' && !column.extra"/>
  <input
       ng-model="inserts[pointers.headings.content.tabInserts - 1].dados[0][columnId].value"
       class="form-control"
       type="number"
       placeholder="{{ column.default }}" 
       ng-if="column.item === 'number' && !column.extra" />
```

I have a weird result : ... when **inserts[pointers.headings.content.tabInserts - 1].dados[0][columnId].value** is a string after the previous one was a number.

Even if {{ column.item === 'number' }} display correctly "False" and the second input will not be displayed, AngularJS continue to send this error :

> Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/ngModel/numfmt?p0=John

Why ? It should not try to do this. Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you get enough info from your error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt?p0=John

> Expected `John` to be a number

You can reproduce it as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in ['Jhon']">
    <td>
      <input type="number" ng-model="x" /> {{ x }} : {{ typeOf(x) }}
    </td>
  </tr>

VM424 angular.min.js:124 Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7-build.5459+sha.21a2f4b/ngModel/numfmt?p0=Jhon
    at VM424 angular.min.js:7
    at Array.<anonymous> (VM424 angular.min.js:187)
    at VM424 angular.min.js:192
    at m.$digest (VM424 angular.min.js:147)
    at m.$apply (VM424 angular.min.js:150)
    at VM424 angular.min.js:22
```

So be sure `inserts[pointers.headings.content.tabInserts - 1].dados[0][columnId].value` is a number and not `Jhon`

If you use number as string, you can use  `string-to-number` directive:

```
.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

*HTML*

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in ['Jhon', '2']">
    <td>
      <input type="number" string-to-number ng-model="x" /> {{ x }} : {{ typeOf(x) }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bErzj45G3vGpVZ4mmWh5?p=preview)</kbd>